# How do I send the output of "Lookup Activity" by email

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to send the output of lookup activity by email with a web activity but I'm not entirely sure how exactly I should create the pipeline.

[image: copy data - Azure SQL Database -> Azure SQL Database Lookup - select count(*) NULL values from specific column ForEach - Settings -> Items -> @activity('Lookup1').output.value Inside ForEach - Set variable and Web activity]

The idea of ​​the pipeline is to check how many rows with null values ​​are in the concrete column and send the result by email.

The error I'm getting is:

[image: Web1 error]

And this is how I'm trying to get the output message from the Lookup activity:

[image: output]

Comment: Paste the body content into the body text field box WITHOUT clicking on 'Add Dynamic Content' in web activity calling Logic App.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce and ended up with similar error.

[image]

Simple solution is that in web activity invoking Logic App, just **copy your body content into the body text field box WITHOUT selecting "Add Dynamic Content"**

Web Activity (Not using Add Dynamic Content):
[image]

Pipeline runs successfully:
[image]

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your swift response. I did what you said and it works now as expected. Thanks a lot!